# Territories that are not connected

Tags: topology, geography

I am looking for territories that are divided between two or more countries in a non-contiguous way. E.g, country A receives the western part of the territory, then country B receives a part to its east, then country A again receives a part to its east, and finally country B receives the eastern part. Where can I find such examples?

Answer (score 1):

These are known as enclaves - one example is the Belgium/Dutch border towns of [Baarle-Hertog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baarle-Hertog) and [Baarle-Nassau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baarle-Nassau).

Until last month there were many enclaves on the Indian/Bangladeshi border but the two countries rationalised them finally.

A google search for [border enclaves](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=border%20enclaves) will find you references to many more.